# How to Set a User-Defined Colormap in Octave?

Tags: plot, colors, octave, contour, colormap

I have a trivial piece of code that calculates some quantity and plots it as contours:

```
%Calculate Biot number vs. h for a selected material
h = (0:5:1000)';
mat = "Copper";
lambda = 386;
r = (0:0.25:50);  %In cm
 R = r./100; %In m
%Calculate matrix of Bi values
% R = length(h) x C = length(r)
Bi = (h.*R)/lambda;
%Contour Plot of results
%Set boundaries at Bi = 0, 0.1, 1
conts = [0, 0.1, 1];
ptitle = ["Biot Number for a ", mat, " Sphere"];
%Create a personalized colormap with 30 values.
%    0<Bi<0.1  Green
%    0.1<=Bi<1 Yellow
%    Bi >= 1   Red
my_green = [229,255,204]./255;
my_yellow = [255,255,204]./255;
my_pink = [255,229,204]./255;
my_cmap = [repmat(my_green, 10, 1); repmat(my_yellow, 10, 1); repmat(my_pink, 10, 1) ];
clf;
colormap (my_cmap);
contourf(h, r, Bi, conts, 'showtext', 'on');
title(ptitle)
xlabel ("h(W/m^2*K)");
ylabel ("r(cm)");
```

The result is missing the intermediate color (yellow):

[image: Result with missing color]

What can be done about this?

Comment: Create a Px3 array and set it as a colormap, `cm = [repmat([0 1 0], L, 1); repmat([1 1 0], M, 1); repmat([1 0 0], N, 1); ]`. The value of `L` `M` and `N` depends on your data.

Comment: Can you expand a little about "The value of L M and N depends on your data."?

Comment: Play around with different values for them and you'll see what I mean. I only meant that if you want your colorbar to be 60% green, 30% yellow and 10% red, make sure you keep a 60:30:10 ratio between L:M:N. If you want to compute the percentages automatically it would require some more tinkering. See also [`caxis`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/caxis.html).

Comment: I see, I'm gonna try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too few contours, so the wrong color is chosen. If you do `contourf(h, r, Bi, 0:0.2:1, 'showtext', 'on');` you get:

[image: More contours]

Also, I'd suggest to make the "green" and the "yellow" more different, as it might be difficult to differentiate them on some displays.

---

Here's what I meant by "playing around with `L, M, N`:

```
conts = [0, 0.1, 1];
ptitle = ["Biot Number for a ", mat, " Sphere"];
%Create a personalized colormap
my_green = [229,255,204]./255;
my_yellow = [255,255,204]./255;
my_pink = [255,229,204]./255;
my_cmap = [repmat(my_green, 10, 1); repmat(my_yellow, 90, 1); repmat(my_pink, 1, 1) ];

figure(); contourf(h, r, Bi, conts, 'showtext', 'on');

colormap (my_cmap);
caxis([0 1.01])
title(ptitle)
xlabel ("h(W/m^2*K)");
ylabel ("r(cm)");
```

[image]

BTW, I ran this on MATLAB R2018a in case you're wondering why you're not getting the exact same thing.

Comment: I know I'm being a tad fastidious, but I need to have at least the contour at 0.1, because that value has a physical meaning.

Comment: No problem, just modify the contour steps as you need.

Comment: @FabioCapezzuoli Check out my edit, you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code below to define countours and to generate the colormap, the process can be automated.

```
conts = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 1];
%Create a personalized colormap with 50 values distributed proportionally to Bi values
step = 50/max(max(Bi));
L = ceil(step*0.1);
M = ceil(step*(1-0.1));
H = ceil(step*(max(max(Bi))-1));
my_green = [229,255,204]./255;
my_yellow = [255,255,204]./255;
my_pink = [255,229,204]./255;
my_cmap = [repmat(my_green, L, 1); repmat(my_yellow, M, 1); repmat(my_pink, H, 1)];
```

Obtaining:

[image]